# I need scroll bar in my menu item in Joomla 3

Tags: css, joomla, joomla3.0

I have this kind of problem. I bought template to my website http://www.ravintolalaite.net/demo/ and it is very nice but my "Uudet" and "Käytetyt" menu items does not show all links under those categories. I think I need some scroll bar to my menu item. But how to do that scroll bar in Joomla?
Or is there any other solution for that problem?

Best regards,
Janne

Answer (score 0):

Try to update **`nexus.css`**

Path: `demo/templates/joomlage0108-view/css/nexus.css`

**Line No: 156**

**Replace with:**

```
#container_header, #container_header-sticky-wrapper {
    z-index: 5000;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative!important;
}
```

Comment: Still it doesn't work. It is ok for mobile devices but in normal laptop it doesn't show all links.

Comment: http://www.ravintolalaite.net/screenshot.png Now I need to split my menu items in multiple columns. How to do that?

Comment: Now I know that I should have two or more menu columns in one item. How to split menu item in two columns?

Comment: I see that this is difficult question because person who sold me that template also doesn't want to answer this question. I can buy plugin but I don't know which plugin really works.